# Windows 7 Live Essential

Tags: download

I wish to Install Windows Live Essentials Wave **4 BETA** on Windows Live Essential 2011 beta but this new update Wave 4, I am not getting site to download. Anybody may help getting me straight site for downloading **4 BETA**

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials-beta)
Its the link to the Beta site from Microsoft. The setup file you can download there is the most actual version of Essential BETA you can get. [Here](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/06/windows-live-essentials-wave-4-public-beta-is-out.ars) you can read the Blogentry which helped me to find it.